# $\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n}\right)(\sin(n x))}{n}$ converges conditionally for $x$ being non-integer multiple of $\pi$

Tags: real-analysis

Summation 
$$\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n}\right)(\sin(n x))}{n}$$
converges conditionally for $x$ being non-integer multiple of $\pi$.
I can be easily shown that it converges absolutely for $x$ being integer multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: Are you asking for the limit of the *sequence* or for the convergence of the *series*?

Answer (score 0):

Partial sum of [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Rate_of_divergence) is $$0<H_n \leq \ln{n}+1$$
$$\frac{\ln{n}}{n} \rightarrow 0, n\rightarrow\infty$$
and $|\sin{(nx)}|\leq 1$. As a result
$$\color{red}{0}\leq\left|\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n}\right)\cdot(\sin(n x))}{n}\right|=\\
\left| \frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{n}\right|\cdot \left| \sin{(nx)}\right|\leq \\
\frac{\ln{n}+1}{n}\rightarrow \color{red}{0}, n\rightarrow\infty$$
according to [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) it converges for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$.