# Conditional convergence of a series involving $sin n \theta$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, conditional-convergence

I recently stumbled upon the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}\right)\frac{\sin n \theta}{n}.$$ Consider all values of $\theta$ except $k \pi$ where $k$ is an integer.
Is the series conditionally convergent?
I know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin n \theta}{n}$ is convergent. But what about this?

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2628434/frac-left1-frac12-frac13-frac1n-right-sinn-xn-co/

Answer (score 0):

Abel's Test implies that: If $a_n$ is monotonically decreasing and tends to $0$, then series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\sin nx$$
is convergent for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$.
Let $a_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$, you can get the idea！

Comment: Ok, but how will I show that it is not absolutely convergent for values of $x$ other than $k \pi$?

Comment: @LegendKiller  Do you know how to show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n)}{n}$ does not converge absolutely?  If so, do you see that this series in absolute value dominates $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|\sin(n)|}{n}$

Comment: Use the fact  $\frac{|\sin(n)|}{n}\geq\frac{\sin^2 n}{n}=\frac{1-\cos 2n}{2n}$, you can prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n)}{n}$ does not converge absolutely.

Comment: @LegendKiller Note that $$\sum_{n=3}^N\left|\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k\right)\frac{\sin(n)}{n}\right|\ge \sum_{n=3}^N \log(n)\frac{|\sin(n)|}{n}>\sum_{n=3}^N\frac{|\sin(n)|}{n}$$